# Is there a way to wire a door jamb switch in parallel with a light switch that wouldn't make a code inspector upset?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I would like my storage/utility room to turn on the lights immediately when I open the door (like a fridge), but I don't want to exclusively use a door jamb switch -- sometimes we need to close the storage room door while someone is in it (say if someone were walking through the hallway) so I'd like to retain a regular toggle switch as well. Essentially I want to

Essentially I want the lights to follow this truth table

| Door State | Toggle State | Lights state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Open | Up | On |
| Open | Down | On |
| Closed | Up | On |
| Closed | Down | Off |

I could get a section of romex and tie it directly to the two gold/screws on my switch and carry it through to the door jamb switch, but that sounds hacky and like it would make a code inspector upset with me. Is there a way to do this that would be in line with electrical codes?

For reference, I'm in Wichita, Kansas

Comment: Great question, and well presented. It comes down to the simple legality of parallel hots. I'm interested.

Comment: Yes, why not a motion detector? That seems to check all your practicality boxes without the hassle. It could be a simple bulb base. I actually have one I'm not using. It's yours if you want to stop by Minnesota.

Comment: What is being stored? should the toggle switch be waterproof or splash protected? That motion detector solution seems a good option.

Comment: @isherwood Honestly, I hadn't even considered a motion detector, that does seem to be significantly less of a hassle and I've upvoted the answer suggesting it -- but am still interested in the legality if such an answer exists.

Comment: I have done basically this (not in Kansas, so this isn't advice about code). I replaced the single toggle with a double, so that one switch isolates the other two, then the other works as per your table. This way the light can be forced off with the door open too (say, I need to leave the door open over night to let paint dry, whatever).

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest a motion detector switch. We have one in a pantry and as soon as you open the door the  lights come on.  They switch off after a minute or so of inactivity (time is adjustable). Also, the switch can be turned on manually and the lights stay on until it's manually turned off.

The good part is motion detector switches are an easy install:  You just swap out the normal switch.  It's worked like a champ now here for 15 years.

EDIT:  OK I realize that this doesn't directly answer the OP question.  But I do think its a better solution.

Comment: This is a better solution for sure -- I'll probably be implementing this solution regardless of legality of what I was going to do.

Comment: Another nice thing about this idea is that if you have things in your hands, as you tend to do with a closet, you don't have to flick any switch.      This becomes a bad idea if the closet door tends to be left open a lot, but in your case as you said it obstructs the hallway, that probably won't happen.

Comment: Where I've seen these frequently used is in public bathrooms in office buildings.  Specifically the single-occupant type bathrooms, not larger ones with multiple stalls, as a person in a stall might not be visible to the detector and you don't want the lights going out before you've finished your business in there...

Comment: You can even get LED lamps with built-in motion sensors, so it would only be a case of changing the lamp.

Comment: I'm thinking for the manual switch part you'd want it outside the closest and with an indicator light for when it's powered.  If not, it'd be too easy to flip it on at some point and then never notice it was left on indefinitely because you're always expecting it on when the door is opened.

Answer (score 8):

The motion detector is an easier and more practical idea and IMO has functional benefits.  But just to answer the question, I don't see any compliance issue with what you want to do.  You just want two switches in parallel.  Run them both as switch loops from the light (or if it's a little pancake then from a junction box).  Use compliant cabling and a compliant jamb switch, there is no issue.   You describe it as hacky to "get a section of Romex" and "Tie it to screws" but that pretty much describes most modern residential wiring. :)

Comment: I think the thing that got me thinking it would be hacky would be to have one line of romex from the light to the toggle, then another from the toggle to the door-jamb switch, it sounds like what you're suggesting is have an individual line from each switch to the light instead. Is that correct?

Comment: That is what I meant.  You could cable it switch-to-switch as well.  Depending on exactly how you cable it, you might need /3 cables.  But there is still no inspection issue.

Comment: Double switch loop (but new, so with neutral even though neutral not being used for these switches) is fine. What you don't want to do is: hot/neutral -> switch 1 and switch 2, switched hot/neutral from each switch to light. The problem is that neutral would not be balanced with the switched hot - code violation (though realistically with a few W of LED not a likely real hazard, but future uses are always unknown so have to follow code).

Comment: Hmmm another problem with this scheme is that if you close the door and left the switch on, you don't know you left the light on and you won't be in the habit of paying attention because usually the door does the job.  So you need a pilot light on the outside or a little glass portal in the door.  :)   Another vote for the motion detector.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution is to take the AC wiring out and make the whole lighting function ultra-low voltage, probably 12V DC.

This will let you run much lighter wiring, and **the local inspector won't care** about anything DC below 50V.  Of course it still has to be fitted in a workmanlike manner.

A simple motion detector for 12V is going to be cheaper than one for mains AC too.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary if there's no reason for it. As you said it still has to be fitted in a workmanlike manner, which suggests they do actually care.